# Redirecting views based on user roles Asp.net Core

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

**I have this controller and I need to redirect views based on user roles:**

````
    ```[Authorize(Roles = "Projects,Projects-Manager")]

    public IActionResult Projects()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Procurment,Procurment-Manager")]

    public IActionResult Procurment()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "HR,HR-Manager")]

    public IActionResult HR()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    //GET: Login 

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }


    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLoginModel userModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return View(userModel);
        }


        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userModel.UserName, userModel.Password, userModel.RememberMe, false);


        if (result.Succeeded && HttpContext.User.IsInRole("HR,HR-Manager"))
        {
            return Redirect(nameof(HR));
        }
        else if (result.Succeeded && HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Projects,Projects-Manager"))
        {
            return Redirect(nameof(Projects));

        }
        else if (result.Succeeded && HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Procurmant,Procurmant-Manager"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Procurment));
        }


        else
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid UserName or Password");
            return View();
        }


    }
````

**and this is startup.cs.**

```
                services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opt =>
                {
                    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                    opt.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "";
                    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
                    opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                })
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
           
                services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, CustomClaimsFactory>();
                services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

                services.AddControllersWithViews();
            }
```

I am getting This Err

(This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7044/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FLogin
HTTP ERROR 404 )

So I am tried to change controller code with many solutions founded in StackOverFlow but still the same.
**Is there any Configuration to be added in startup?**

**UPDATE:**
There was a Mistake in Login view Name and I fixed it, But still not directed to the Views and I get HTTP ERROR 405

Comment: Do you have Account/Login  page?

Comment: Yes and there was Mistake & I Update Me question, Kindly take a look.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like only authenticated/authorized users are allowed to use the Login post method in the controller. Try `[AllowAnonymous]` rather than `[Authorize]` on that method. 405 error code is a "Not Allowed" error

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLoginModel userModel)
```

Comment: Yes your Correct, I did that and now my err in console shwoing this((jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5:201
    at jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5:240)) While I am sure that I Load Mentioned Jquery files!!

Comment: Yes your Correct, I did that and now my err in console shwoing this((jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5:201
    at jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5:240)) While I am sure that I Load Mentioned Jquery files!!

Comment: are you loading the main jquery js file before loading jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js ? Can you post your login Page?

Comment: Yes I did, Here Is The Partial Login View (https://codeshare.io/Od6nLN)

Comment: please also post your _ValidationScriptsPartial

Comment: <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: this issue has moved beyond the original question and the actual correct answer, which apparently had side effects in your code. Ideally if you would please accept the answer I provided as it did get you past the initial error, I would be grateful. As for your current error, please load jquery the same way you're loading the jquery validation libs.  please remove the script link from the page, and instead add it to _validationscriptspartial and use asp.net root path. specifically `<script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>`. if you look at console network, do you see jquery loaded?